# How to use UIPickerview in xcode 4.2 storyboard?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, uipickerview, storyboard

I am trying to use a `UIPickerView` for my project but I can't figure out how to use them in the storyboard format.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: It's not really different from before storyboards. Maybe you could say what part exactly is confusing you? Is it positioning it in the view? Or connecting its datasource and delegate?

Comment: well I am new to xcode and all of the examples I can find using UIPickerviews involve .xib files and view applications.  I am doing a master-detail application and there is no option for delegating file's owner, I also tried figuring out how to involve .xib files into the storyboard but couldn't.

Comment: Last I heard, Storyboards and nib files are mutually exclusive. Correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Answer (score 3):

This post takes you through the process w/xcode 4.2

[UIPickerView - How to populate](http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/07/uipickerview-how-to-populate.html)

Answer (score 1):

I verified and it behaves the same for storyboards as it does for xib files.  After adding the `UIPickerView` to a view, right click it to reveal the `delegate` and `datasource` outlets.  Double check that your `UIViewController` for the view is a `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`, or you will not be able to attach these outlets unless it is.